# Select combobox value and send it to next page by hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select combo box , I have to catch the value of selected item of combo box and set it for a hidden field so that I can catch it in next page. But I am not able to do it. Can any one help me in this.

My form tag is as follow ,

```
<form class="well" name="ddm" id="ddm" style="margin-left: 30px;" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller/SMSManagementController">

 <input type="hidden" name="flowName" value="PERSIST_SCHOOLYEAR_INFO" >
 <input type="hidden" name="schoolYearId" id="schoolYearId" value="">
```

next my select tag is ,

```
    <div class="form-group control-group">
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="schoolYear" id="schoolYear">
    <option>--Select Grade--</option>
                 <c:forEach var="grade" items="${gradeInfo}">
    <option value="${grade.getDropDownId()}">${grade.getDropDownName()}</option>
       </c:forEach>
    </select>

    </div>
```

I used javascript to do this as,

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 var schoolYear = document.form.schoolYea.value;
 document.ddm.schoolYearId.value = schoolYear;
 document.write (schoolYear);
</script>
```

What is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: Why do you need a hidden field? You can get the combobox's value in the next page.

Comment: How can I get in next page . .

Comment: if you want your value to be sent when your combobox value changed then your combobox should start with: `<select class="form-control selectpicker" name="schoolYear" id="schoolYear" onChange="window.open('your_next_page_url?id=' + this.value, '_self')">`

Comment: @BatuZet, why the `window.open`? Raghavendra, is the selectbox in the form?

Answer (score 0):

Guys I solved it like this. ,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
$('#schoolYear').change(function() {
    // get value from combobox
    var x = $(this).val();
    // set it to hidden fields
    $('#schoolYearId').val(x);
});
});
</script>
```

it worked.